# Get an element from a list next to a specific element when started from end of the list

Tags: python, list

I have a list
items_list = [1,8,2,5,8,4,abc,gd,5,8]

I need to find 8 just after abc if started from end of the list. How can I do that ?

for example:-
I have a list of files and everyday new file gets added to that list, I don't know the index of that file but I just know that I need to pick a file that comes just before a speicific file.

list is like this –
[str_123.txt, zap_3456.log, str_678.txt, bcv_7886.log, abc.current, str_987.txt, zap_654.log]

I just need to pick str_678.txt, this file changes everyday and its position is also not constant but one thing is sure that this .txt file will come just before abc.current file. So what can I do in this case.

Expected output is :- str_678.txt

Comment: So what would be the output? Please add real Python code (abc is not a string) for your input

Comment: Index is unknown, just need to pick the first occurence of 8 just after abc when started form end.

Comment: So what have you code so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Why 8? Why "abc"? What should be the output if there is no 8 after "abc"? All these are questions that will make easier for someone to answer

Comment: I have a list of files and everyday new file gets added to that list, I don't know the index of that file but I just know that I need to pick a file that comes just before a speicific file. So forex :- list is like this – 
[str_123.txt, zap_3456.log, str_678.txt, bcv_7886.log, abc.current, str_987.txt, zap_654.log], I just need to pick str_678.txt, this file changes everyday and its position is alos not constant but one thing is sure that this .txt file will come just before abc.current file. So what can I do in this case.

Comment: Please add this new information to your question

Comment: So what is the expected output?

Comment: "need to pick str_678.txt".... Based on what?

Comment: What exactly is the relationship between the str, zap and bcv files? If each of these are meant to be together, then ideally you should maybe group those together, not just try to work with a "list of files"... Especially when some files could be missing and indicies aren't consistent

Comment: this is the '.txt' file and it will come just after abc.current if started from end of the list , there may be other file between this '.txt' file and abc.current file but I need the first occurence of this '.txt' file after abc.current if started from end of the list.

Comment: I did 'ls -ltar' , i got list of files, Now the files generated at different date and time, the '.txt' file I need comes just before abc.current file. but Index may vary because it could be either next to abc.cuurent or 2nd next or 3rd next, but it will be '.txt' file only.

Comment: Again, edit the post to clarify the problem better

Comment: Relying on lexicographic file ordering is probably going to end up in bugs. Just because a number appears ahead of `a` doesn't guarantee that's always going to be the file you're looking for, or that'll it be "before" all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
files = ["str_123.txt", "zap_3456.log", "str_678.txt", "bcv_7886.log", "abc.current", "str_987.txt", "zap_654.log"]

# find the current index of abc.current
current_index = files.index("abc.current")

# get the next element that ends with .txt iterating backwards (-1) from current index
result = next(file for file in files[current_index::-1] if file.endswith(".txt"))

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
str_678.txt
```

Comment: Well, thankyou! this works. This is what I was looking for. I was doing the same just missed this part [current_index::-1]. Hence got wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the list using a while loop from the end.

When you find `'abc'`, you set a flag to `True` and start looking for the first number `8`.

When you find the number `8` you return the `index` position and the actual number.

```py
def find_first_8_after_abc(items):
    start = False
    index = len(items) - 1
    while index >= 0:
        if start and items[index] == 8:
            return (index, items[index])
        if items[index] == 'abc':
            start = True
        index -= 1


items_list = [1,8,2,5,8,4,'abc','gd',5,8]

location = find_first_8_after_abc(items_list)

print(location)
```

Will print `(4, 8)`.